# Why is this query ignoring the filter?

Tags: php, sorting, filter

The query below works correctly if I REMOVE the "and table.field = '$filter' OR table.field='$otherfilter'".  If i add this part then it shows me results for people I am not authorized to see.  I definetely need to add that part so it shows me filtered results.  How do I structure this so it shows me the correct results using: and table.field = '$filter' OR table.field='$otherfilter'

Code:

```
  //$filter = "23943409"
    $filter2 = "$username";


  $sql = "SELECT table.field, table2.field, table.field, table.field,
  table.field, table.field, table.field FROM table 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table.field = table2.field 
  WHERE table.field='$id' and table.field='$id' 
  and table.field = '$filter' OR table.field='$otherfilter' 
  ORDER BY table.id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";

  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

  if ($result == "")
  {
  echo "";
  }
  echo "";


  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  if($rows == 0)
  {
  print("");

 }
 elseif($rows > 0)
 {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {

 $field = $row['field'];

 print("$field");
 }

 }
```

Comment: You commented out $filter, so this variable is empty. Thus your query becomes: and table.field = ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `AND (table.field = '$filter' OR table.field = '$otherfilter')`.  Note the parenthesis around the clause.  I'm assuming you have obfuscated the code and replaced the actual field names with "field".

Comment: the funny thing is that it works correctly elsewhere but not taking chances.  Adding your suggestion to evertyhwere i use this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place parentheses around your filters:

```
AND (table.field = '$filter' OR table.field='$otherfilter')
```

Otherwise your logic is off.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying "field is an apple **AND** field is an orange" with the `table.field=$id AND table.field = $filter`. Hopefully that's just you being lazy with obfuscating your table/fieldnames, but if you are using the same table.field combo for those two values, then you're excluding ALL records since a single record field cannot have more than one value in it at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably dealing with precedence issues between `and` and `or`.  Try:

```
"SELECT table.field, table2.field, table.field, table.field,
  table.field, table.field, table.field FROM table 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table.field = table2.field 
  WHERE table.field='$id' and table.field='$id' 
  and (table.field = '$filter' OR table.field='$otherfilter')
  ORDER BY table.id DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```